# Having a issue with css styling for a button that pops out when hovered over

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am very new to CSS as I just started learning it. I've been trying to develop a website as creating a product is the best way for me to learn.

I've created a button that works okay but when hovered the icon pops under the button for a second and then comes back up. I would like to fix that but I'm not sure how.

I've written this;

```css
.sidebar-wrapper {
  height: 83%;
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
}

.sidebar-btn {
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
  height: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 35%;
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
  width: 110px;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar-btn img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 50px;
}

.sidebar-btn label {
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 19;
}

.sidebar-btn:hover {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar-btn:hover label {
  display: inline;
}

.sidebar-clr {
  width: 7px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-btn">
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <label> Profile </label>
    <div class="sidebar-clr bg-blue"></div>
    <img class="sidebar-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ff0000" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details about your problem ?

Comment: Because of floats etc... your `label` is actually pushing the object out of the way when it appears. Delete your label and you will see the flash disappear. Also, you should never have to use `&nbsp;` for layout based whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `label` to *after* your image, as all the inline styling and scaling means that as it display the label, the `image` gets pushed out of the way (because it is *after* your `label`) and then things snap again when they recalculate themselves the next draw frame. But I think in general there should be better ways to do this, but I am unsure what you are trying to accomplish - the label doesn't actually display in your snippet, it just turns itself to display as block, but the area remains empty, so... Pretty sure a mix of `absolute` and `relative` positioning or `flexbox`, or `background-size transition` woudl probably work better for your purpose, but I can't say.

```css
.sidebar-wrapper {
  height: 83%;
  width: 110px;
  position: absolute;
}

.sidebar-btn {
  background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33, 0.5);
  height: 8%;
  margin-bottom: 35%;
  animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideInFromLeft;
  width: 110px;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar-btn img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  width: 50px;
}

.sidebar-btn label {
  font-family: 'Monoton', cursive;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 19;
}

.sidebar-btn:hover {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar-btn:hover label {
  display: inline;
}

.sidebar-clr {
  width: 7px;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-btn">
    <img class="sidebar-img" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ff0000" />
    <label> Profile </label>
    <div class="sidebar-clr bg-blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but it only creates a new problem. When hovered over, the label will now flash under the button instead of the image...